# Count the number letter occurrences in a string

Tags: python, string, count, digits

I would like to code in python a summary of the number of atoms in a molecular formula (string). The string is a letter followed by a number (when there is no number it's counted as one).

Input: C3H7NO2C3H7NO2S
Output: C6H14N2O4S

The only letters that I have are: O,C,N,H and S.

Comment: What language or tool are you using?

Comment: find the first letter (C), check that there is a number next to it (yes, 3) - so remember C and a count of 3. Repeat for next number. When no number follows the element (like the N), its count is 1. When you get another C, add to the previous count. Now code that in your language-of-choice

Comment: I've added the required language *as tag* - that way you attract the correct people

Answer (score 0):

A C# "oneliner" that you certainly cannot send in as a homework solution:

```cs
var s = "C3H7NO2C3H7NO2S";
var s2 = string.Join(" ",Regex.Split(s, @"([A-Z]\d*)")
        .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
        .Select(x => Regex.Match(x, @"([A-Z])(\d*)"))
        .Select(m => new {elt = m.Groups[1].Value, cnt = m.Groups.Count > 2 ? m.Groups[2].Value : "1"})
        .Select(e => new {e.elt, cnt = string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.cnt) ? 1 : int.Parse(e.cnt)})
        .GroupBy(e => e.elt)
        .Select(g => $"{g.Key}{g.Sum(x=>x.cnt)}")
        );

// s2 contains "C6 H14 N2 O4 S1"
```

[fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/V6HPiT)

- first get the element-count pairs (where count is optional)
- then split those into element and count (missing count = 1)
- then group by element and sum the counts
- then join up to a single string

Answer (score 0):

def convert(aa_seq):

```
temp = re.findall('\d+|\D+', str_atoms) #split string to numbers and chars
#print(temp)

# dictionary
dicta = {}

# list to dictionary
for i in range(int(0.5 * len(temp))):
    key = temp[2 * i] # set atom as key
    val = int(temp[2 * i + 1]) #set value as the number that follows
    # print(key + ' = ' + str(val))
    if (key in dicta): #add value to existing key
        dicta[key] += val
    else: # if key does not exist create this
        dicta[key] = val
print(dicta)

# dictionary to string
final_str = ''
for x in dicta:
    final_str += x + str(dicta[x])
print(str_atoms)
print(final_str)
```